# Spacing between two floating point values in a normalized system?

Tags: numerical-analysis

Let x be a given nonzero floating-point number in a normalized system, and let y be an adjacent floating-point number, also non-zero.

a) What's the minimum possible spacing between x and y? b) What's the maximum possible spacing between x and y?

I know Floating-point number system is characterized by four integers,

x = +/- (d_0 + d1/B + d2/B + ... + d_(p-1)/B^(p-1)*B^E, where

0 <= d_i, <= B - 1, i = 0,...,p-1 and L <= E <= U

I can't seem to correlate the relationship between the equation I have and the minimum/maximum possible spacing possible between the two adjacent FP numbers. Help please!

numerical-methods

Comment: seems off-topic to me.  why don't you repost this in the math SE?

Comment: they sent me here.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280927/spacing-between-two-floating-point-values-in-a-normalized-system
i feel like this is more math but they dont seem to think so

Comment: well mathoverflow is for math experts, i think.  but why not math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: tried that before also.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426021/spacing-between-two-floating-point-values-in-a-normalized-system
seems like everyone just points to other directories..

Comment: yeah, that's weird.  i'm sorry.  maybe it has to do with your use of the term `floating point` number?  don't you mean `real` number?